# DD MON YYYY to YYMMn6

Tags: sql, date, sas, prompt

I am writing a program in Proc SQL. the program takes various input files, where the filenames change from month to month (i.e. myfile_YYYY_MM or mytable_YYYYMM, or mydata_YY_M).

Most of the program is now dynamic, and the user is asked to input reporting date via a prompt when executing the program.

The "Prompt Date" (&Rep_Date.) in the code has format DD MON YYYY (31may2018), and I need to set up one macro variable transforming this value to format YYMMn6 (i.e. 201805).

The syntax looks like this:

```
 %let Period = input("&Rep_Date."d,YYMMN.);
```

This worked when trying to create a d9 variable, and for creating a month/year variable, like this:

```
 %let date = "&Rep_Date."d; /*Last day execution month*/
 %let year = %sysfunc(year("&Rep_Date."d));
 %let month = %sysfunc(month("&rep_Date."d));
```

for some reason, the same does not work when trying to format the date to YYMMn6.

I also tried creating the variable "Period" in a temporary SAS table like this, but again no luck:

```
 Data dates; 
 Period = input((&Rep_date.,6.), yymmn6.);
 format Period yymmn6.;
 Run;
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why does this have SQL tag?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is because of the fact that you are using just the `input` function in your `%let` statement.. This won't resolve properly. The right thing would be to use the `%sysfunc` macro function with the `input` function. The issue is that `sysfunc` doesn't work with the input function. Hence, the solution is to use `%sysfunc(putn())`. Here is an example.

Edit:
Not sure what you're trying to achieve but the `%window` function (assuming you're using Windows) allows you to take input through a prompt and then create a macro variable from the input. Here is an example:

> ```
> %global Period;
>
> %window info
>   #5 @5 'Please enter date:'
>   #5 @40 _Date 9 attr=underline;
> %display info;
> %put &_Date.;
>
>
> %macro da(Rep_Date=&_Date);
> %let Period = %sysfunc(putn("&Rep_Date."d,YYMMN.)); 
> %put &Period.;
> %mend;
>
> %da();
> ```

This should work.

Comment: Hi JD, 
That works, but I am trying to make the input for the variable Period be the input from the date prompt window. Is there anyway to make "%da(Rep_Date = &Rep_Date.)? tried quotation marks, etc. did not want to work!

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is going wrong ? You are mixing contexts and misconstruing a representation as a literal (*literally - pun literally intended*).

**In short**

Have your macro code utilize the date representation value as the basis for a literal value that is used in a `putN()` invoked by `%sysfunc`.

```
%let Rep_Date = 18-JUN-2018; * some date representation;
%let Period = %sysfunc(PUTN("&Rep_Date."D,YYMMN.));
%put NOTE: Period=%superq(Period);
```

**In Long**

From the Glossary in "SAS Help and Documentation" (F1)

- **SAS date value**
  an integer that represents a date in SAS software. The integer represents the number of days between January 1, 1960, and another specified date. For example, the SAS date value 366 represents the calendar date January 1, 1961.
- **SAS date constant**
  a string in the form 'ddMMMyy'd or 'ddMMMyyyy'd that represents a date in a SAS statement. The string is enclosed in quotation marks and is followed by the character d (for example, '6JUL01'd, '06JUL01'd, '6 JUL2001'd, or '06JUL2001'd).
- **date and time format**
  instructions that tell SAS how to write numeric values as dates, times, and datetimes.
- **date and time informat**
  the instructions that tell SAS how to read numeric values that are represented as dates, times, and datetimes.

Textual values of the form `DD MON YYYY` is one form of a representation of a date. The form with four year digits can be input using the *instructions* inherent in the informat `DATE11.`.  The SAS date literals (SAS date constant) are of the form `DDMONYYYY`D with or without a variety of spaces, dashes, slashes, etc.

Another code variation similar to the 'In short' would input the date text using a specific format (`date11.`) instead of relying on the system doing a date literal interpretation.

```
%let Rep_Date_text_representation = 18/JUN/2018;
%let Rep_Date_value = %sysfunc(inputN(&Rep_Date_text_representation,date11.));
%let Period = %sysfunc(putn(&Rep_Date_Value,yymmn.));

%put NOTE: &=Rep_Date_text_representation ;
%put NOTE: &=Rep_Date_value;
%put NOTE: &=Period;
```